# Can I buy games off of the PS Store without being on the console?

Tags: ps4, psn

I bought a PS4 Slim and I want to buy Battlefield 1 on PSN, but my PS4 hasn't arrived yet. Can I buy the game without using a physical console?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, as long as you have a Playstation Network account, you can purchase things [online](https://store.playstation.com/) or through the [Playstation mobile app](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/explore/ps4/app/).

From the app:

[image: PSN Battlefield 1]

Once you get your PS4, just log into your account and go to your Purchased section of your Library (far right on the main menu) and Battlefield 1 should be there and available for download.

Another useful thing is that once you *have* a PS4 set up, you can remotely tell it to install games you've purchased from the app. It helps for those times your coworker convinces you to buy a game at work and you want to play as soon as you get home.

Comment: Don't forget you can also go to the PlayStation store on any web browser which does the same thing as the app.